# How to reposition search bar kitchen store theme magento

Tags: search

Hi I'm hoping someone will be able to tell me how to reposition the search bar in this template http://dev-mdl.net/kitchen_store/magento/.

I want to move it into the position that the 'Default welcome msg!' is in currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having access to the template files, the search box is probably in a file called something like header.phtml in a folder something like /template/page/html/

If you look into the layout file catalogsearch.xml you'll see where the search box is referenced.

```
<reference name="top.bar">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

In my version of header.phtml the search box is rendered by this call:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
```

So, to get the search box moved, I would change where the call to getChildHtml('topBar') is made in the file - so, in my case I'd look to see where the welcome msg is rendered (
The default msg is rendered something like this: `<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome()?></p>`) & replace it with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>`

You'll then no doubt need to change the css to get the search box to look how you want.
Cheers